# c++: Remove element from container and get it back

Tags: c++, stl, containers

Is there a built-in method that removes and element (i.e. from map given a key) and returns the removed element?

Comment: Use [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) to access the element then [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) to remove it (at its position) from the container.

Comment: @0x499602D2 1. I don't use C++11 yet. 2. This what I'm asking, if I need to do this, if you know it for sure, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do this, you can however store the element by accessing it and then erase it.
Erasing requires you to specify key.If it's a multi-map you should erase with position.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can use (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template<typename T>
typename T::mapped_type removeAndReturn(T& mp, const typename T::key_type& val) {
    auto it = mp.find(val);
    auto value = std::move(it->second);
    mp.erase(it);
    return value;
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, int> m;
    m[3] = 4;
    std::cout << "Map is empty: " << std::boolalpha << m.empty() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Value returned: " << rm_and_return(m, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Map is empty: " << std::boolalpha << m.empty() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Map is empty: false
Value returned: 4
Map is empty: true
```