# STL associative containers: erasing and getting back the (noncopyable) element

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I am using STL associative containers (`std::set` and `std::map`) with keys which hold a `std::unique_ptr<>` instance. The key definition is equivalent to following:

```
struct Key
{
    std::unique_ptr<Object> object;
    bool operator== (const Key& rhs) const { return object->equal (*rhs.object); }
    bool operator<  (const Key& rhs) const { return object->less (*rhs.object); }
}
```

It is known that STL associative containers (esp. since C++11) do not have a way to obtain a non-const reference to the key to move from. And my keys are noncopyable, so [c++: Remove element from container and get it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254900/c-remove-element-from-container-and-get-it-back) does not work.

Is there a non-UB way to overcome this problem?

My current solution is following:

```
template <typename T>
using map_pair_type = std::pair<typename T::key_type, typename T::mapped_type>;

template <typename T>
typename T::value_type take_set (T& container, typename T::iterator iterator)
{
    typename T::value_type result = std::move (const_cast<typename T::value_type&> (*iterator));
    container.erase (iterator);
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
map_pair_type<T> take_map (T& container, typename T::iterator iterator)
{
    map_pair_type<T> result {
        std::move (const_cast<typename T::key_type&> (iterator->first)),
        std::move (iterator->second)
    };
    container.erase (iterator);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: _"Is there a non-UB way to overcome this problem?"_ No. [N3645](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3645.pdf) might have helped, but the proposal was rejected and hasn't been re-submitted again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of these:

> Really sorry.  We tried to make this work and couldn't get it through
>   committee.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3586.pdf

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3645.pdf

Your solution is as good as it gets as far as I know.  Your map solution does exhibit undefined behavior.  And it will go seriously bad if the second move throws an exception.  Other than that, I suspect it will work.  And I suspect I'll get down voted for saying that.

The reason for the UB is that the key is defined as `const` (as opposed to just being referenced by a const reference).  Casting away `const` in that situation (and having a move constructor modify the object) is UB.

Had N3586 been accepted, you could just:

```
move_only_type mot = move(*s.remove(s.begin()));
```

or:

```
move_only_key mok = move(m.remove(m.begin())->first);
```

N3586/N3645 made a good showing in committee.  It was discussed and made it through the working group stage, only to be shot down in full committee.  The concern is that the std::lib would have to commit UB in order to implement it.  It has not been resubmitted.

**Update**

One can now do this in C++17, but the member function is called `extract` instead of `remove`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

If I manage to do something with exception safety *(RAII-style iterator "eraser" maybe?)*, will it remain UB?

Comment: And one more follow-up question. What's the status of that proposal (the latter)? Was it rejected, or not reviewed yet, or rejected-and-will-be-resubmitted?..

Comment: Casting the `const` away is never UB. Attempting to modify a `const` object is UB.

Comment: @Columbo: Moving from an object doesn't count as modifying it? You're right though in that the wording of this answer is arguably a little misleading in that regard.

Comment: Fair point.  I've attempted to make the answer more accurate.

Comment: "Your map solution does exhibit undefined behavior." Does this mean the set solution is not UB? Also I assume doing this to unordered associative containers is UB as well, right?

Comment: The UB comes from `const_cast` of `.first` of a `pair<const key, value>`.  Because the variable is declared `const` (as opposed to just a `const&` of a non-`const` variable), the UB comes into play.